# Copy several files and overwriting only if the size of the file differs from the file that has the same name

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I am looking for a program that:

- can copy several files and overwriting only if the size of the file differs from the file that has the same name.
- works on Windows 7

If possible:

- GUI
- free

---

Example:

```
Folder A:
a.jpg 20KB
b.jpg 5KB
c.jpg 15KB

Folder B:
a.jpg 20KB
b.jpg 2KB
```

If I copy Folder A to Folder B, I want Folder B to contain the same as folder A at the end of the operation, but I don't want the program to copy a.jpg again (because a.jpg in Folder A has the same size as a.jpg in Folder B).

In other words, just like we can do in FileZilla:

[image]

---

TeraCopy doesn't have this function (can only choose to overwrite is the target folder has the file that is older than the source folder's file):

[image]

[Copy Handler](http://www.copyhandler.com/) doesn't seem to have this function either:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for selecting the size over the date attribute? I think date is more reliable (replacing a character in a text file won't change the size for example), and you'd be able to use the Windows intrinsic ``Robocopy`` command (which has several GUI front-ends)

Answer (score 2):

Copying files except when they look identical is what [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is all about. You can install rsync as part of your favorite collection of Unix tools (I use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)) or one of the various rsync GUIs for Windows. The command line is

```
rsync --size-only -a "Folder A/" "Folder B/"
```

(note the slashes at the end, without them `rsync` would create `Folder A` as a subdirectory of `Folder B`). By default (without the `--size-only` option), rsync skips files if they have the same size and modification time on both sides, which may be ok for you.

Some rsync GUIs are targeted at remote backups and probably won't help you. One that looks appropriate (but I haven't used it, so I can't confirm) is [grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't not in Windows (in Windows is what you see is what you get) unless you are thinking to use third party solution like CuteFTP files transfer. here is the link for more information. Hope this was helpful

http://help.globalscape.com/help/cuteftp7/smart_overwrite_options.htm

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a third-party application, but not FTP :)

Comment: Franck try FastCopy http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en

Answer (score 0):

As SolutionSurfers said in one comment, you can use [FastCopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCopy):

- free
- portable version available
- Windows XP/Vista/7/8/8.1/10; Windows Server 2003/2008/2012
- has an option "Diff (Size/date): Copy if size or date is different, or if it doesn't exist (in default)"

[image]